# How do I use Bootstrap scrollspy?

Tags: 8, theming

I would like to use [Bootstrap's scrollspy plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy) in Drupal 8.
So I edited the `html.html.twig` file replacing

```
<body{{ attributes.addClass(body_classes) }}>
```

With

```
<body{{ attributes.addClass(body_classes) }} data-spy="scroll" data-target=".nav-scrollspy" data-offset="50" >
```

Where `.nav-scrollspy` is the class of my navigation block. Additionally I added the following JavaScript to my theme:

```
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '.nav-scrollspy' });
```

But as this does not work I were wandering whether or not this plugin is already integrated in [Drupals Bootstrap theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap). Apparently not, as I could not locate such a file in `themes/bootstrap/js/`.

Unfortunately I did not find such a file in the web neither, so I am asking my self, where to get it and how to add it to Drupal?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK your bootstrap theme will be having `bootstrap.js` or `bootstrap.min.js` included. Generally, scrollspy plugin related code will be inside these files.

So try to recheck whether you have added `nav-scrollspy` to your div element. I think you might need to have 'id' for your div element and a proper link to it.

```
<!-- The navbar - The <a> elements are used to jump to a section in the scrollable area -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
</nav>

<!-- Section 1 -->
<div id="section1">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this page and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Also in Drupal 8, caching is a bit aggressive so try to rebuild your cache and check again. For better understanding refer http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-bootstraps-affix-scrollspy-plugins/